# xslt2+ How to combine groups with any matching elements and remove duplicates of elements

Tags: xslt

This is my solution to combine groups with any matching elements and remove duplicates of elements.
For example, I sketched a simple input and what the output should be. If two groups have the same elements, then the groups are combined into one with all elements except repetitions.
Are there alternative approaches ?

```
<xsl:variable name="in">
   <g>
      <i>8</i>
      <i>2</i>
   </g>
   <g>
      <i>2</i>
      <i>4</i>
   </g>
   <g>
      <i>4</i>
      <i>5</i>
   </g>
   <g>
      <i>6</i>
      <i>7</i>
   </g>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <out>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$in/g/i" group-by="k2:iin(.,$in)[1]">
    <g>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by=".">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </g>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </out>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="k2:iin">
 <xsl:param name="i"/> <!-- current catch -->
 <xsl:param name="in"/> <!-- const catch scope -->
 <xsl:sequence select="
let $xi:=$in/g[i = $i]/i return
if($xi[not(. = $i)])then
 k2:iin($xi,$in) else
$xi
 "/>
</xsl:function>


<out>
   <g>
      <i>8</i>
      <i>2</i>
      <i>4</i>
      <i>5</i>
   </g>
   <g>
      <i>6</i>
      <i>7</i>
   </g>
</out>
```

Comment: Comparisons like `$in/g[i = $i]` usually suggest you could use a key `<xsl:key name="by-i" match="g" use="i"/>`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it necessary to edit expression to call the key() for using <xsl:key ..> ?

Comment: You would replace the comparison with a call to the `key` function i.e. instead of `$in/g[i = $i]/i` you would use `key('by-id', $i, $in)/i`.

Comment: And `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>` can simply be written as `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` as the first item in the current group is the context item inside of `for-each-group`.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the suggestions made in comments, you could replace the inner xsl:for-each-group by

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(current-group())">
   <i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Though `distinct-values` doesn't guarantee to retain order, whereas `xsl:for-each-group` does. So there's no real benefit over your approach (but you did ask for alternatives...)

Comment: not only the order suffered here, but also the elements have to be recreated manually

Answer (score 0):

As the question says `xslt2+` I thought about a compact or elegant XSLT approach, it seems you don't really need to use grouping but could just store sequence of arrays of integers. Nevertheless, somehow that attempt to write a recursive processing approach using `fold-left` has not really given a compact or elegant approach, I post it just to show the attempt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="i-value-groups" 
        select="fold-left(g, (), function($value, $g) {
                  let $i-values := distinct-values($g/i/xs:integer(.)),
                      $group := $value[?* = $i-values],
                      $group-pos := for $pos in 1 to count($value) return $pos[exists($value[?* = $i-values])]
                  return 
                    if (exists($group))
                    then (subsequence($value, 1, $group-pos - 1), array { distinct-values(($group?*, $i-values)) }, subsequence($value, $group-pos + 1))
                    else ($value, array { $i-values })                  
                 }
                )"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$i-value-groups">
        <g>
          <xsl:for-each select="?*">
            <i>{.}</i>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </g>
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes an input sample like

```
<data>
   <g>
      <i>8</i>
      <i>2</i>
   </g>
   <g>
      <i>2</i>
      <i>4</i>
   </g>
   <g>
      <i>4</i>
      <i>5</i>
   </g>
   <g>
      <i>6</i>
      <i>7</i>
   </g>
</data>
```

Of course, if instead of the plain integers, the `g` elements would need to be "grouped", you could use the same `fold-left` approach returning a sequence of arrays, or, in the following sample, a sequence of maps (in XSLT/XPath 4 parcels or records):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:collect-parcels" as="map(xs:string, element(g)*)*">
    <xsl:param name="input-sequence" as="element(g)*"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="fold-left(
                $input-sequence,
                (), 
                function($parcel-ac, $g) {
                  let $i-elements := $g/i,
                      $matching-parcel-pos := 
                        for $pos in 1 to count($parcel-ac)
                        return $pos[exists($parcel-ac[$pos][?value/i = $i-elements])],
                      $matching-parcel := $parcel-ac[$matching-parcel-pos]
                  return 
                    if (exists($matching-parcel))
                    then (subsequence($parcel-ac, 1, $matching-parcel-pos - 1), map:entry('value', ($matching-parcel?value, $g)), subsequence($parcel-ac, $matching-parcel-pos + 1))
                    else ($parcel-ac, map:entry('value', $g))                  
                }
              )"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="mf:collect-parcels(g)">
        <g>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="?value/i" group-by=".">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </g>
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it is possible to rise to the level of Groups (sequences of Items are unnecessary)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <out>
  <xsl:for-each-group
  select="$in/g"
  group-by="k2:g(.)[1]"
  >
    <g>
    <xsl:for-each-group
    select="current-group()/i"
    group-by="."
    >
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </g>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </out>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="k2:g">
 <xsl:param name="g"/>
 <xsl:sequence select="
let $xg:=$g[1]/../g[i[. = $g/i]] return
if(count($xg) gt count($g))then k2:g($xg) else
$xg
 "/>
</xsl:function>
```

To try to avoid an overhead in group-by, you can first collect all the Groups that disappear. (Of course, to pay for this complication of control over the solution)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="gmap" select="k2:gmap(1,$in/g[1],map{})"/>
 <xsl:message select="$gmap"/>
 <out>
  <xsl:comment select="'+gmap()'"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group
  select="$in/g"
  group-by="
let $x:=(1 + count(preceding-sibling::g)) return
($gmap($x),$x)[1]
  "
  >
    <g>
    <xsl:for-each-group
    select="current-group()/i"
    group-by="."
    >
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </g>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </out>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="k2:g">
 <xsl:param name="g"/>
 <xsl:sequence select="
let $xg:=$g[1]/../g[i[. = $g/i]] return
if(count($xg) gt count($g))then k2:g($xg) else
$xg
 "/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="k2:gmap">
 <xsl:param name="gpos"/>
 <xsl:param name="g"/>
 <xsl:param name="gmap"/>
 <xsl:sequence select="
if(empty($g))then $gmap else
let $xg:=if($gmap($gpos))then () else k2:g($g) return
k2:gmap(
 $gpos + 1
,$g/following-sibling::g[1]
,if(empty($xg[2]))then $gmap else
 map:merge(
  ($gmap
  ,for $x in subsequence($xg,2) return
   map:entry(1 + count($x/preceding-sibling::g),$gpos)
  )
 )
)
 "/>
</xsl:function>
```